# Buttons are being displayed in different colors

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap v3  for my website. And this is how I declare buttons all across the web site

```
<input type="button" class="btn ui-button" id="xx" value="xxxx" />
```

In IE 11 and Fire Fox the button's RGB value is 240,240,240  and in chrome it is 221,221,221. How can I make them similar?

Comment: Try adding class `btn-default`, perhaps? [http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to bootstrap necessarily, Chrome just displays a slightly different *default color* than Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Microsoft Edge. You can confirm this by running the following in a blank document, lacking any reference to external stylesheets and/or bootstrap:

```js
document.body.textContent = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( "button" ) )
).backgroundColor;
```

As you'll note, Chrome returns `221` for R, G, and B. Firefox, IE, and Edge all return `240`. To resolve this, you need only to provide a background color. You can do this by using a bootstrap class (such as `btn-default`), or via your own styles:

```css
button {
    background-color: rgb( 240, 240, 240 );
}
```

With this, the previous test would yield `240` in all aforementioned browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much... Worked like a charm.